# Design The Key in KV Store

Tags: nosql

How keys should be designed in a Key-Value Store?

For example if there is a need for querying users based on their emails (a manual secondary index), should the key be `user:email_index:user@domain.com` or `user:email_index:<SOME_FIXED_WIDTH_HASH>`?

If so, what hash algorithm should be used? Is there a sequential hash algorithm for hashing strings that preserves the sequence? (in case we need to sort strings)

Maybe `:id` should be added at the end - this is just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: The only hard requirement for such a key is that it uniquely identifies each value.

Comment: It does (like in case of emails). But big keys reduce performance. Is there a sequential hash function for strings? (IMO this should be the correct approach)

Comment: another requirement might be that it is anonymised